# How to generate random triangle on a unit circle

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find out the probability of the center of a unit circle falling inside a triangle. The vertexes of the triangle are randomly picked on the unit circle.

My idea is to pick a random float `x` in the range `(-1.0, 1.0)` and then randomly select up or down. This will get me one point `(x, +/-sqrt(1 - x*x))`

```
import Data.Random

main = do
 x <- randomRIO (-1.0,1.0)
 let y =  (sample (randomElement [-1,1])) * sqrt(1-x*x))   -- I can't make this line work
```

So how do I select a random element from a `[Int]` ?

Comment: you probably can simply pick 3 angles in `[-pi, pi)`. finding out if the center is in the triangle is just a matter of finding the largest side, and finding if the third point is on the correct side of it.

Comment: I don't understand the point of `randomly select up or down`.

Comment: You'll need to use `y <- (sample ...)` as well.  If `randomElement` also has type `[Int] -> IO Int`, then you'll need to use an intermediate variable `sign <- randomElement [-1, 1]`.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks. Better with your random angle method.

Comment: If you're still unfamiliar with monads in Haskell, I would recommend implementing this with the simpler `System.Random` from the `random` package where every action executes in the IO monad, which does make things a bit simpler to understand at first compared to the more abstract structures provided by `Data.Random`.  Since you're just doing everything in `main` right now anyway, just using `IO` would get your program working first, then you can move to a more complex but safer solution.

Comment: @njzk2 also your algorithm for testing if the center is inside of the triangle seems wrong... even if the point is on the "correct" side it can still be outside of the triangle

Comment: @bheklilr how to choose between these two packages when dealing with random number? i only found out about the random-fu package a few hours ago and got confused

Comment: @osager Random number generation with Haskell is a bit of a confusing topic for new users because it seems so complicated.  The base package from which (almost) all random numbers are generated is `random`, which ships with the Haskell Platform.  It provides methods for iteratively generating a random number from a seed where each call returns a random number and a new seed, and also an `IO` version of each function that gets the system's standard generator, then sets the system's generator to the newly generated one.  `MonadRandom` builds on top of it, and `random-fu` builds on top of that...

Comment: ... The `random-fu` package is designed for high level computing, and it has a lot of methods for generating different kinds of random distributions, and a lot of convenience functions, but it comes at the cost of complexity.  I consider that for most purposes, the `MonadRandom` package is a great choice for just getting some uniformly distributed random numbers in a safe and easy way, and you can do it without having to execute `IO` actions every time you get a random number so it's a bit more efficient.  I can provide an example as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't speak Haskell, but to choose a point on a circle with even distribution, the variable you need to pick is the angle.

```
angle <- randomRIO(-pi, pi)
```

then

```
y = sin(angle)
x = cos(angle)
```

Pick 3 angles for your 3 dots and that gives you a random triangle.

As for testing if the center is in the triangle, I am fairly certain, though I have no demonstration so far, that you can go as follows:

- Find the longest edge. The edge splits the circle in 2 parts
- If the third vertex is in the smallest part, the center is not in the triangle
- Else, it is

### Edit, Demonstration

- Let, ABC be a triangle in the circle of center D.
- **Let AB be the longest edge**
- Let C be on the largest half of the circle cut by AB
- If D is not in ABC, then either AC or BC (for simplicity and since this is just naming convention, let assume AC) is the edge of the triangle that between AB and D
- AC and AB being chords of the circle, the closest to the center is the longest
- **AC is longer than AB**

### How to apply this to angles only

From the previous demonstration, it quickly appears that if all 3 points are in the same half, the center is not in the triangle, otherwise it is.

The point is therefore to determine that the maximum distance between 2 points is pi.

Thanks to J. Abrahamson, we can compute the difference between all three points' angles, and sum the smaller two, return true if the sum is greater than pi.

The actual measurement of the distance between 2 points goes like this, as we need the absolute and most direct distance between the 2:

- Compute the absolute distance `diff = abs(theta1 - theta2)`
- If this is more than pi, use `2 * pi - diff`

Comment: There's a faster, mod-free test: compute the difference between all three points' angles, sum the smaller two, return true if the sum is greater than pi.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: that's about where I was trying to go, but trigonometry was a long time ago. Also, the difference between 3pi/4 and -3pi/4 is 3/2pi, but should really be 1/2pi, so I think there is still modulos.

Comment: probably something like `abs(((x + pi) % 2pi) - pi)`

Comment: If they're all within the same "loop" then you can sort and subtract to get the differences and that ought to be mod-free.

Comment: define `in the same loop`?

Comment: Sorry, all canonicalized together, within 2pi of one another

Comment: within 2pi is not sufficient. take the example of pi/6 and -pi/6. The difference is 5pi/3, while the distance we are looking for is pi/3.

Comment: I don't think so. Did you try to draw it?

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to do this without giving it adequate thought. Instead of spitballing I'll think harder about it before commenting again.

Comment: No problem, I haven't done any trigonometry for at least several years, and angles measurements have never sounded easy, so I may have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

An example of this using the `MonadRandom` package instead (`cabal install MonadRandom`):

```
import Control.Monad.Random

type R a = Rand StdGen a  -- Just a type alias for less typing

type Point = (Double, Double)
type Triangle = (Point, Point, Point)

-- Monadic action
genAngle :: R Double
genAngle = getRandomR (-pi, pi)

-- Monadic action
genPoint :: R Point
genPoint = do
    x <- genAngle
    return (cos x, sin x)

-- Monadic action
genTriangle :: R Triangle
genTriangle = do
    a <- genPoint
    b <- genPoint
    c <- genPoint
    return (a, b, c)

-- Pure function
containsOrigin :: Triangle -> Bool
containsOrigin (a, b, c) = ???  -- You get to implement this (@njzk2 has given some pointers)

-- Monadic action
genTriangles :: R [Triangle]
genTriangles = do
    tri <- genTriangle
    rest <- genTriangles -- Recursion to get infinite list
    return $ tri : rest
-- Monadic action
genTrianglesWithOrigin :: R [Triangle]
genTrianglesWithOrigin = do
    triangles <- genTriangles
    return $ filter containsOrigin triangles

main :: IO ()
main = do
    triangles <- fmap (take 10) $ evalRandIO genTrianglesWithOrigin
    mapM_ print triangles
```

If you want more reading on why `MonadRandom` is nicer than the base `random` package, I would recommend looking at [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) section of Learn You A Haskell.  Basically, `MonadRandom` builds a nicer interface where not everything is in `IO` (which is dangerous, who knows what an `IO` function does) and provides some easy functions for generating random numbers, whereas the `random` package just provides the most barebones functionality possible.  In fact, the `Rand` monad is nothing more than the `State` monad in disguise, it just keeps up with the state of your generator seed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the MonadRandom package, the uniform function will give you a random value from a list of values ([Int] in your case). I'm on my phone, but finding the package shouldn't be too tough. If you want to use a different distribution, look into random-fu.